# get value from std::map in c++ which has custom type

Tags: c++, c++11

I have initialized a map as:

```
typedef void*   ProxyClientHandler;
std::map<string,ProxyClientHandler> connectedClient;
```

And I am inserting values into this map as

```
ProxyClientHandler client;
string device;
connectedClient.insert ( std::pair<string,ProxyClientHandler>(device,client) );
```

no error returns upto this.

But when i am going to access the value of given relevant key as

```
string deviceId; 
ProxyClientHandler client = connectedClient.find(deviceId);
```

it gives me an error:

> error: cannot convert ‘std::map, void*>::iterator {aka std::_Rb_tree_iterator, void*> >}’ to ‘ProxyClientHandler {aka void*}’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int DHProxyClientDelPort(ProxyClientHandler, int)’

how can i fix this issue???

Comment: `find` returns an iterator. You want `at` or `[]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::map::find()` returns iterator, usualy you can use it as this:

```
auto it = map.find( key );
if( it == map.end() ) {
   // key not found
}
ProxyClientHandler client = it->second;
```

Answer (score 0):

`find` returns an iterator.

```
std::map<string,ProxyClientHandler>::iterator it = connectedClient.find(deviceId);
```

---

Or, if you validated (or just know by your code's logic) that an element with the key `deviceId` is inside the `map`, you should use `[]`:

```
ProxyClientHandler client = connectedClient[deviceId];
```

Comment: I am afraid using `operator[]` in this case would be not safe or not effective or both. I would not recommend it.

Comment: @Slava Agreed. The behavior of `std::map::operator[]` probably seemed like a good idea at the time they designed it, but it's way too willing to hide logic errors. Even if you're 99.9% sure the key is safe, `myMap.at(key)` is just as easy, and will localize bugs instead of concealing them.